# On equivalent ways to obtain the modulus of the gradient.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry

Recently I was following a seminar of one of the great living Italian mathematicians: Luigi Ambrosio (recently his student Alessio Figalli won the fields medal). One of his slides was dealing with the Eulerian/Lagrangian duality (a concept I was not so familiar with):

[image]

I have two questions: Could one provide some intuition as to why these 3 ways of computing the modulus of the gradient are the same and could I have a reference to a proof of this fact? I am interested in all three equivalencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include any hypotheses, but of course we need to assume $f$ is differentiable at $x$ (or else you can have, for example, a function with $\nabla f(x)=0$ but some $\partial_v f(x)\ne 0$). But then it's standard from multivariable calculus that
$$\partial_v f(x) = \nabla f(x)\cdot v,$$
and so you achieve the maximum directional derivative by taking the unit vector $v$ in the direction of $\nabla f(x)$. This is the second formula (the sup is actually a max).

The third formula arises by computing directional derivatives as derivatives along curves. Indeed, if $\gamma$ is any curve with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, then by the chain rule we have 
$$\partial v f(x) = (f\circ \gamma)'(0) = (d_xf)(\gamma'(0)).$$

You can relate the first formula to the second, for example, by passing to a sequence $y_k\to x$ with $\dfrac{y_k-x}{\|y_k-x\|}\to v$, and then the quotient in question is approaching the directional derivative in direction $v$. Thus, you get the limsup by taking such a sequence that gives the optimal $v$.

**EDIT**: Note that the definition of the derivative $d_x f$ tells us that
$$f(y_k)-f(x) = d_xf(y_k-x) + o(\|y_k-x\|),$$
and so
$$\frac{f(y_k)-f(x)}{\|y_k-x\|} = d_x f\big(\frac{y_k-x}{\|y_k-x\|}\big) + \epsilon,$$
where $\epsilon\to 0$ as $y_k\to x$.
This means that when we chose the sequence $y_k\to x$ so that $\dfrac{y_k-x}{\|y_k-x\|}\to v$, we see that
$$\frac{f(y_k)-f(x)}{\|y_k-x\|)} \to d_xf(v) = \partial_v f(x),$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain a bit more how to relate the first formula to the second?

Comment: I just wanted to say, I just realized who you are and that your course on youtube is absolutely amazing and leaves me in awe. The way you teach students is truly remarkable. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, @Monolite. I'm glad you find the lectures helpful :)